# Track changes in a cell array with string elements in Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I have a cell array with 5 columns and about 5000 rows with string elements. E.g.:

> 1997 Charles House Materials Chemicals

The years go from 1997 to 2013 and you find repetitions while the years pass by. What I would like to get is a new cell array with the cases in which the combination of the second and third column change. E.g. original cell array:

> 1997 Charles House Materials Chemicals %initial
>
> 1997 Rita Office Financial Bank %initial
>
> 1998 Rita Office Financial Bank %no change
>
> 1999 Charles House Materials Chemicals %no change
>
> 2000 Charles Office Materials Chemicals %change in the 2nd column
>
> 2001 Charles Office Materials Chemicals %no change
>
> 2003 Rita Star Financial Bank %change in the 2nd column
>
> 2005 Charles Castle Materials Chemicals %change in the 2nd column
>
> 2010 Rita Moon Financial Bank %change in the 2nd column

I would like for my new array to give me the first/original row and the cases in which you
observe a change. E.g. output:

> 1997 Charles House Materials Chemicals
>
> 1997 Rita Office Financial Bank
>
> 2000 Charles Office Materials Chemicals
>
> 2003 Rita Star Financial Bank
>
> 2005 Charles Castle Materials Chemicals
>
> 2010 Rita Moon Financial Bank

My problem is mainly related to the fact I am dealing with strings. If one could help me I would appreciate. Thanks a lot for your availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
%// Assuming input_cellarr is the input cell array

[~,~,col2id] = unique(input_cellarr(:,2),'stable')
[~,~,col3id] = unique(input_cellarr(:,3),'stable')

[~,unqrows] = unique([col2id col3id],'rows','stable')
out = input_cellarr(unqrows,:) %// Desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I filtered out the first column because the year does not matter. Then, you have to compare the previous with the next line. This is done using `X(1:end-1,2:end)` and `X(2:end,2:end))`. Only if row wise equal, nothing has change.

```
changes=all(strcmpi(X(1:end-1,2:end),X(2:end,2:end)),2)
%at this point we are missing the first line
changes=[true;changes]
%finally use logical indexing to select the relevant data.
result=X(changes,:);
```

Comment: I tried your code, it works, but strangely for the result I get a cell array with one row only.